# /init.d/function + python version

Tags: python, init.d, celeryd, python-daemon

I am trying to daemonize celery and celerybeat. I have downloaded the celeryd and celeybeat files from github and placed them in `/etc/init.d/` (celery and celerybeat) with the corresponding config files under `/etc/default/`.

My problem is that when I run these two files, celeryd and celerybeat use system python (2.4), and as a result cannot find other installed applications under python 2.7. Python 2.7 is in `~/.bashrc` and `/.bash_profile` files, so I do not have any problems running other applications, except when workers fail to work. When I run `python ...../manage.py celery` ( with all options) everything works like a charm.

Please let me know how I can force `/init.d/function` to run python2.7.

I have tried to implement `#! /bin/sh python`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

scripts in `/etc/init.d` are usually run as *root* on system startup. root's `~/.bashrc` (that is `/root/.bashrc`) will look totally different from yours (e.g. `/home/reza/.bashrc`).
your shell will behave slightly differently if you are running it interactively or not.

hence there is no use in trying to run the python interpreter through `/bin/sh`, it only adds overhead.

what you want is to add a proper [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) that tells the system which interpreter to use for your script.

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

will use the `python2.7` binary installed in `/usr/bin`.
(so whenever you run `/etc/init.d/foo.py` the system really runs `/usr/bin/python2.7 /etc/init.d/foo.py`)